# Predict a single vector with the new spark.ml API to avoid groupByKey() after a flatMap()?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

Is there a way to predict a single vector with the new spark.ml API?  I want to do this within a map() to avoid calling groupByKey() after a flatMap():

**Current code (pyspark):**

```
% Given 'model', 'rdd', and a function 'split_element' that splits an
% element of the RDD into a list of elements (and assuming each element
% has a value and a key so that groupByKey will work to merge them later)

split_rdd = rdd.flatMap(split_element)
split_results = model.transform(split_rdd.toDF()).rdd
return split_results.groupByKey()
```

**Desired code:**

```
split_rdd = rdd.map(split_element)
split_results = split_rdd.map(lambda elem_list: [model.transformOne(elem) for elem in elem_list])
return split_results
```